# How to handle KeyError in HTTP response when grabbing data (using Django requests)

Tags: django, http, python-requests

I try to make API requests to fetch data from a third party API to manipulate/render the data into my dashboard. Including the responsed data everything runs well so far, but it seems something is wrong with the dictionary/keys within the json api data.

In particular I would like to grab the values of the keys 'name' and 'country' which are correctly fetched via the http response according to the Django debug.

I always end up with a KeyError as shown below.

What do I miss here? (I am not sure if this is important, but my linter tells me that json is imported but unused within the views.py)

**This is the response:**

```
Variable    Value
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/dashboard/'>
response    
<Response [200]>
team_data   
{'api': {'ENDOINTS': {'countries': {'countries': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/countries'},
                      'events': {'events': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/events/{fixture_id}'},
                      'fixtures': {'date': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/fixtures/date/{date}',
                                   'h2h': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/fixtures/h2h/{team_1}/{team_2}',
                                   'id': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/fixtures/id/{fixture_id}',
                                   'league': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/fixtures/league/{league_id}',
                                   'live': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/fixtures/live',
                                   'team': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/fixtures/team/{team_id}'},
                      'leagues': {'country': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/leagues/country/{country_name}/{season}',
                                  'league': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/leagues/league/{league_id}',
                                  'leagues': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/leagues',
                                  'season': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/leagues/season/{season}'},
                      'lineups': {'lineups': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/lineups/{fixture_id}'},
                      'odds': {'bookmakers': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/odds/bookmakers/',
                               'fixture': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/odds/fixture/{fixture_id}',
                               'labels': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/odds/labels/',
                               'league': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/odds/league/{league_id}'},
                      'players': {'player': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/players/player/{player_id}',
                                  'seasons': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/players/seasons',
                                  'team': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/players/team/{team_id}'},
                      'seasons': {'seasons': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/seasons'},
                      'standings': {'leagueTable': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/leagueTable/{league_id}'},
                      'statistics': {'fixture': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/statistics/fixture/{fixture_id}',
                                     'team': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/statistics/{league_id}/{team_id}'},
                      'teams': {'league': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/teams/league/{league_id}',
                                'team': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/teams/team/{team_id}'},
                      'transfers': {'player': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/transfers/player/{player_id}',
                                    'team': 'https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/transfers/team/{team_id}'}},
         'WARNING': 'THIS IS A DEMO AND DOES NOT REPRESENT THE ENTIRE API. THE '
                    'DATA IS LIMITED AND NOT UP TO DATE AND SERVES ONLY AS AN '
                    'EXAMPLE. FOR PRODUCTION ENVIRONEMENT USE : '
                    'HTTPS://API-FOOTBALL-V1.P.RAPIDAPI.COM/V2/',
         'results': 1,
         'teams': [{'code': None,
                    'country': 'Brazil',
                    'founded': 1909,
                    'logo': 'Not available in Demo',
                    'name': 'Internacional',
                    'team_id': 33,
                    'venue_address': 'Avenida Padre Cacique 891, Bairro Menino '
                                     'Deus',
                    'venue_capacity': 50128,
                    'venue_city': 'Porto Alegre, Rio Grande do Sul',
                    'venue_name': 'Estádio José Pinheiro Borda',
                    'venue_surface': 'grass'}]}}
```

**This is my views function:**

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render
import json

def team_update(request):
    response = requests.get('http://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/teams/team/33')
    team_data = response.json()
    print(team_data)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {
        'name': team_data['name'],
        'country': team_data['country'],
    })
```

**This is the error:**

```
KeyError at /dashboard/
'name'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/
Django Version: 2.2.5
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'name'
Exception Location: C:\Users\Jonas \Desktop\dasocc\dasocc_site\dasocc_app\views.py in team_update, line 25
```

Thank you very much for your input in advance.

## -#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-

**Update/Solution:**

```
def team_update(request):
    response = requests.get('http://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/teams/team/33')
    team_data = response.json()
    teams = team_data.get('api', {}).get('teams', [])
    if teams and len(teams) == 1:
        teams = teams[0]
        context = {'name': teams['name'], 'country': teams['country']}
    return render(request, 'index.html', {
        'name': teams['name'],
        'country': teams['country'],
    })
```

Comment: `team_data` has the keys `WARNING`, `results` and `teams` so why do you think `team_data['name']` should work?

Comment: uhm good hint, thanks. I just tried it with `teams` key and get the same error though.

Comment: As far as I can see when trying the api myself, the top-level key is `api`. Look at the output of `print(team_data)`, it's not what you pasted here.

Comment: Ah right. I missed the top part of the response. So I have to handle a nested key structure, that being said I have to use another approach to grab the required data out of the dic? << I will update the top post with the correct response.

Comment: No, this is just a regular python dict with nested objects, just access them as you would with any nested python dict. The only thing is `teams` is a list, so you might want to check that it contains one item before accessing it via `[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to safely access your team from such a response is to make sure all the way that you don't access keys that might not exist or objects in a list that might not exist. So don't access keys using `[key]` but use `get()`. If the api returns `{'status': 'error', 'errors': {...}}` then your code would still crash if you just assume it has a key "api":

```
teams = team_data.get('api', {}).get('teams', [])
if isinstance(teams, list) and len(teams) == 1:
   team = teams[0]
   context = {'name': team['name'], 'country': team['country']} # might also crash if for some reason the api returns a team without country, but not likely
else:
   # handle the issue teams is empty or there's more than 1 team or teams isn't what was expected
```

Comment: Working! I will post the working example into my initial post. Could you maybe tell me what this means using average joe words? ;p `if teams and len(teams) == 1:
   team = teams[0]` Thanks

Comment: that's just checking that the teams **list** isn't empty and contains exactly one team. If that's the case, we access the first element in the list.

Comment: Actually we can skip `if teams` since we always assign the empty list. But we might want to make sure it is a list. I've changed it above.